# Android and iOS billing for multi-platform saas

Tags: google-play, app-store, stripe-payments

Just wondering if someone can clear this up for me as its kind of a grey area and not sure what to do.
I have a website that is split into frontend and api and has a subscription service provided by stripe on the api. I am now making apps in ionic for both apple and google stores but Im unsure of how the payments will work on the platforms, ideally i would like to just stick to using stripe but Ive been reading about both stores and this is where I need guidance.
From what I have read it seems to be that I have to use google play billing and apples alternative. Do I have to use these for the apps going into their respective stores or can I continue to use stripe within the apps? As i see it its a multi platform saas. So why cant I just send the card info to my api for charging?(I know theres alot of security involved and its not as trivial as I make it out to be)
Ive been reading conflicting statements from multiple sites and Im just not sure which is correct and the docs on [google play billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview?hl=en#GetSample) make no reference to this. Its a multiplatform service so can I just send on the card details to my api 
But what I have found is that apple have this

> 3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services: Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired elsewhere, including consumable items in multi-platform games, provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app. You must not directly or indirectly target iOS users to use a purchasing method other than in-app purchase, and your general communications about other purchasing methods must not discourage use of in-app purchase.

Which to me states that I have to use Apple Pay and make no reference to my other payment methods for fear of being refused from the store.

Comment: For iOS at least, I believe that you can only use Stripe to pay for physical/external goods. If it's payment for an-app item like a premium subscription, Apple requires you to use their IAPs(instead of Stripe) https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-vs-in-app-purchases

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for Apple. For Google Play the best place to answer this sort of question is the [Developer policy center](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/). In the [Monetization and Ads section](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/) it says

> - Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded on Google Play must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment, except for the following cases:
>
>   - Payment is solely for physical products
>   - Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

You should read all of the linked page and decide what category the stuff you are selling falls into.